# MAgento2.3.0 how to Update automatic indexing - cron job to set up to re-index automaticaly/periodically

Tags: magento2.3, reindex, cronjobs

I am using MAgento2.3.0 website i need  to  Update automatic indexing - cron job to set up to re-index automaticaly/periodically

if any one idea how to setup please reply me

Answer (score 0):

You have to need set cron for Update automatic indexing.

**Create the cron job**

To create a cron job for the Magento file system owner, enter the following command as a user with root privileges:

`crontab -u <Magento file system owner username> -e`

**For example,**

`crontab -u magento_user -e`

A text editor displays. (You might need to choose a text editor first.)

```
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento install dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento install dir>/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento install dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

**Where**

`<path to php binary> is the absolute file system path to your PHP binary`

`<magento install dir> is the directory in which you installed the Magento software; for example, /var/www`

`| grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" filters this message from the log, making any errors easier to spot`

Run command: `php bin/magento cron:run`

**For further information:**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html